# Matte finish over satin finish?

Tags: bathroom

I just removed wallpaper, cleaned the walls, repaired, painted a primer sealer, and painted with a satin finish in my bathroom.  Hate it! Can I use a different color with a matte finish over this satin that I painted on with a brush. New paint will be close in color?

Comment: Definitely, the finish won't show through a new layer of paint.

Comment: @HartCO Post that as an answer

Answer (score 3):

A matte or eggshell, or pretty well any other finish, will cover over the old sheen. With it being freshly painted and primed, you shouldn't have any issues with the paint adhering. As long as the walls were prepped well before the coat you already put on, there shouldn't be any issues.

Keep in mind though, flat finishes are harder to clean, and in a bathroom with a shower, eggshell is is a good choice as a minimum. Many paints are mold resistant now, and there are several brands with eggshell being ok for bathrooms, but the flat sheens may not be.